# Unable to deploy Azure storage account with lifecycle management rules through Bicep

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-bicep

When I was trying to deploy a storage account with life cycle management rules through Bicep I got error. The What-if says the two new rules to be created but the actual apply failed.

Error:

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "HttpResourceNotFound",
      "message": "The request url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxxxxxxx/managementPolicies/Rule2?api-version=2022-09-01 is not found."
    },
    {
      "code": "HttpResourceNotFound",
      "message": "The request url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxxxxxxxxx/managementPolicies/Rule1?api-version=2022-09-01 is not found."
    }
  ]
}
```

Bicep:

```
resource blob_storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: storageAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    azureFilesIdentityBasedAuthentication: {
      directoryServiceOptions: 'None'
    }
    minimumTlsVersion: tlsVersion
    isHnsEnabled: true
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      virtualNetworkRules: [for subnet in subnetList: {
        id: subnet
        action: 'Allow'
        state: 'Succeeded'
      }]
      ipRules: []
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
    }
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}

resource default_blob 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2022-09-01' = {
  parent: blob_storage
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    deleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: retentionDays
    }
  }
}

resource containers 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2022-09-01' = [for containerName in containerList: {
  parent: default_blob
  name: containerName
}]

resource lifecycleRule 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies@2022-09-01' = [for lifecycleRule in lifecycleManagementRules: {
  name: '${lifecycleRule.ruleName}'
  parent: blob_storage
  properties: {
    policy: {
      rules: lifecycleRule
    }
  }
}]
```

Param:

```
"lifecycleManagementRules": {
            "value": [
            {
              "ruleName": "Rule1",
              "enabled": true,
              "type": "Lifecycle",
              "definition": {
                "actions": {
                  "baseBlob": {
                    "delete": {
                      "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": 30
                    }
                  }
                },
                "filters": {
                  "blobTypes": [
                    "blockBlob",
                    "pageBlob"
                  ],
                  "prefixMatch": "logs/"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "ruleName": "Rule2",
              "enabled": true,
              "type": "Lifecycle",
              "definition": {
                "actions": {
                  "baseBlob": {
                    "delete": {
                      "daysAfterLastAccessTimeGreaterThan": 60
                    }
                  }
                },
                "filters": {
                  "blobTypes": [
                    "blockBlob"
                  ],
                  "prefixMatch": "backups/"
                }
              }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I have tried different Bicep API versions for the managementPolicies and confirmed the sub ID, resource group name and storage account name are all correct.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the two new `rules` were not created or identified during deployment, and that the `request URL` could not be located. Your code appears to be correct to me, but make sure that you are using a valid and supported `Api version` for the `management policies`. I used Api version `@2021-09-01` and was able to correctly deploy rules as well as storage accounts.

*I made few modifications to your bicep code and attached below.*

```bash
param location string
param sku string
resource blob_storage 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'newcarolinestore'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: sku
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  properties: {
    azureFilesIdentityBasedAuthentication: {
      directoryServiceOptions: 'None'
    }
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    isHnsEnabled: true
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
    encryption: {
      services: {
        file: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
        blob: {
          keyType: 'Account'
          enabled: true
        }
      }
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage'
    }
    accessTier: 'Hot'
  }
}

resource default_blob 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2022-09-01' = {
  parent: blob_storage
  name: 'default'
  properties: {
    deleteRetentionPolicy: {
      enabled: true
      days: 90
    }
  }
}

resource container   'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2022-09-01' = {
  name: 'newcarolinestore/default/mycontainer'
  dependsOn: [
      blob_storage
  ]
}

resource lifecycleRule 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies@2021-09-01' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: blob_storage
  properties: {
    policy: {
      rules: [
        {
          enabled: true
          name: 'Rule1'
          type: 'Lifecycle'
          definition: {
            actions: {
              baseBlob: {
                tierToCool: {
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: 30
                }
                tierToArchive: {
                  daysAfterLastTierChangeGreaterThan: 7
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: 100
                }
                delete: {
                  daysAfterModificationGreaterThan: 60
                }
              }
            }
            filters: {
              blobTypes: [
                'blockBlob'
              ]
              "prefixMatch": "backups/"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

***Deployed the above bicep code in Azure CLI as shown below.***

```bash
az deployment group create --resource-group caroline --name rollout03 --template-file jb.bicep
```

[image]

[image]

Refer [article](https://dev.to/massimobonanni/bicep-storage-account-lifecycle-management-1c5b) by @Massimo Bonanni for more relevant information on the lifecycle management rules.

Comment: Have this sorted, the issue was the name of managementPolicies has to be 'default' in the main file.